# Multi-step ahead forecasting using ML models with horizon feature

Tags: time-series, forecasting

All academic literature I could find on this topic distinguishes between recursive forecasting (forecasting y_{t+1}, then using it as an input to forecast y_{t+2} etc) or direct forecasting using a separately trained model for each horizon (e.g. in Bontempi, G., Ben Taieb, S., Le Borgne, YA. (2013). Machine Learning Strategies for Time Series Forecasting). These are the approaches taken by the libraries I have seen as well (e.g. darts, nixtla)

In practice I have been also using a single model with horizon feature, which specifies the prediction horizon for each row. Essentially this approaches concatenates all the data sets used for direct forecasting with an addition of horizon column. This approach is strangely mostly overlooked in literature except few blogs, such as: https://towardsdatascience.com/forecast-multiple-horizons-an-example-with-weather-data-8d5fa4321e07

Are there any academic studies which study this approach and compare it with more traditional ones listed above that I have missed? What are your own experiences / intuition if any?